# Evenly distribute N number of queries amongst S number of servers

Tags: java

Here is the problem: Need to distribute N number of queries amongst S number of Servers.Have come up with this.The solution is allocating queries to servers but deleting the previous count of the number of queries the server has.Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Servers<T> {
    public int serverId;

    public ArrayList<Queries> queryList;
    public Servers()
    {

    }

    public int getServerId() {
        return serverId;
    }
    public ArrayList<Queries> getqueryList() {
        return queryList;
    }
    public void setqueryList(ArrayList<Queries> queryList) {
        this.queryList = queryList;
    }
    public void setServerId(int serverId) {
        this.serverId = serverId;
    }


}
```

Queries class:

```
public class Queries {
    private static final int noOfServers=10; 
    private String query;
    private int queryId;
    private int size=0;
    private Servers[] ser=new Servers[noOfServers];
//getters and setters for instance variables for Queries class <not included>
public int allocateM(Queries query)
    {
        ArrayList<Queries> queryList=new ArrayList<Queries>();
        int i=size;
        if(i < ser.length)
        {
            qList.add(query);
            ser[i].setqueryList(qList);
            System.out.println("size" + ser[i].getqueryList());
            size++;
        }
        else    if(i==ser.length)
        {
            size=0;
            i=0;


        }



        return ser[i].serverId;
    }
```